# Should this pointer be acting this way? Basic C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, c-strings

From my understanding, `pName` should be a pointer with the value of the memory location of the char `name`.
Which means, when I dereference the pointer variable `pName` in the second `printf` statement, it should just print the string of characters "Cameron". BUT IT DOESNT! Could someone help this noob out :)?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[] = "Cameron";
    char * pName = &name;

    printf("Printing string of characters: %s\n", name);
    printf("Dereferencing pointer and printing string: %s\n", *pName);
    printf("Printing pointer: %p\n", &name);
    printf("Printing pointer another way %p\n", pName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Printing pointer: %p\n", &name);` --> `printf("Printing pointer: %p\n", (void *)name);`

Comment: `"%s"` required a pointer to a string. Not a `char`. You compiler might have told you something about "parameters not matching format specifier..."

Comment: @DavidRanieri Using `&` to `name` isn't invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT I don't get you, I didn't use `&` in my comment

Comment: @Gerhardh Before that, compilers should give warnings for converting pointer types at `char * pName = &name;`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Why did you removed `&` and wrote `printf("Printing pointer: %p\n", (void *)name);`?

Comment: @MikeCAT Because the `%p` specifier must be used with a cast to `void *`

Comment: @Gerhardh It does mention that initialization from incompatible pointer type, but then goes on to say expects arugent of type 'char *' but got 'int'. Is what you're saying that I should use 'code'    %c\n", *pName)    'code'

Comment: @DavidRanieri `printf("Printing pointer: %p\n", (void*)&name);` is also valid, so I don't think it can be the reason why the `&` is dropped.

Comment: What do you want to print? Only `'C'` `"Cameron"`? Strings are printed with `%s`

Comment: @Gerhardh I want to print the entire string. But i'm trying to do it by dereferencing the pointer of the name. My original understanding was that I would use %s in printf and then *pName which should give me "Cameron"

Comment: @MikeCAT ah, ok, you're right, I don't know why I removed it :(

Comment: In second `printf` use `pName` instead of `*pName`. `%s` expects address of char array, not single char. And `char * pName = &name;` can be written as `char * pName = name;`

Comment: You must ensure that after deferencing your pointer you still get a pointer to `char` that you can pass to `printf`. This is not the case with your pointer. Check the available answer for a way to do it.

Comment: You should get an error message for `char * pName = &name;`, after that all bets are off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pName` is a `char*`, a pointer to char. So when you do `*pName`, you get a `char` which is not a string that you can print with `%s`.

Instead of

```
char *pName = &name;
```

you need:

```
char (*pName)[] = &name; // a pointer to an array of chars.
```

Now your dereference/printf will work as expected.

Also the format `%p` requires it argument to be of type `void*`. So you need to cast the arguments to `void*` in printf calls.

See [7.21.6.1 The fprintf function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> p     The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer
>   is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm not using the void* and it seems to be working as intended, however i'll start using it from now on as I'm sure it's standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration of a character array

```
char name[] = "Cameron";
```

is equivalent to the following declaration

```
char name[8] = { 'C', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'o', 'n', '\0' };
```

That is the type of the object `name` is `char[8]`.

You could write for example using a typedef

```
typedef char T[8];
```

and then declare the array like

```
T name = { 'C', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'o', 'n', '\0' };
```

So a declaration of a pointer to the array will look like

```
T *pName = &name;
```

where T as it was shown above is `char[8]`. So substituting the alias name for the type it denotes you will have

```
char ( *pName )[8] = name;
```

To output the string pointed to by the pointer you may now write

```
printf("Dereferencing pointer and printing string: %s\n", *pName);
```

The dereferencing the pointer `*pName` gives lvalue of the array that in turn implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and has the type `char *`. So to use the conversion specifier `%s` yo shall supply an expression of the type `char *`.

As for this declaration

```
char * pName = &name;
```

when it is incorrect because in the left side hand there is an object of the type `char *` while in the right hand side there is an expression of the type `char ( * )[8]` and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

You could just write

```
char * pName = name;
```

As it was said above the lvalue of the array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and has the type `char *`. And you may write using this pointer

```
printf("Dereferencing pointer and printing string: %s\n", pName);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

```
char name[] = "Cameron";

char * pName = &name;
```

By the initialization of `pName`,`name` already decays to a pointer to the first element of the array `name`, actually `name[0]`.

Thus, `&name` is pointer to an array of 8 characters, type `char (*)[8]`, not a `char*`. It is invalid to assign a `char*` by a `char (*)[]`.

This should have gave you a diagnostic. Never ignore compiler warnings.

Use:

```
char * pName = name;
```

instead.

---

#### 2.

```
printf("Dereferencing pointer and printing string: %s\n", *pName);
```

The `%s` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `char *` what `pName` already is. Dereferencing `pName` obtains a `char` which is invalid.

Use:

```
printf("Dereferencing pointer and printing string: %s\n", pName);
```

instead.

---

Side note:

To be standard-compliant `%p` shall have an argument of type `void*`.